# IBOutlets not showing

Tags: xcode, ios, interface, interface-builder, iboutlet

I created three `IBOutlet`s in a .h but when I go to Interface Builder and go to Referencing Outlets or right click on the object that I want to connect to one of the outlets. It just doesn't display the outlets I made. How do I find and connect the images in IB to these. My goal is to make custom buttons, I have the images out in IB and have set the highlighted state. And I want the images to auto switch to the highlighted state when touchupInside is triggered.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *brown
    IBOutlet UIButton *red
    IBOutlet UIButton *blue


}

-(void)brownPressed
-(void)redPressed
-(void)bluePressed
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code you posted is accurate, you are missing 6 semicolons. Interface Builder won't be able to properly parse the header file without them and so it won't show any `IBOutlet`s.

Try changing the code to the following:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *brown;
    IBOutlet UIButton *red;
    IBOutlet UIButton *blue;

}

-(void)brownPressed;
-(void)redPressed;
-(void)bluePressed;
@end
```

Comment: Although not mentioned in the question, the OP will probably want those `voids` as `IBActions`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is in reference to Xcode 4

If you changed the name of the .xib manually, don't forget to check these IB setting in the right pane:

Identity and Type: File Name
should be:

newName.xib

Custom Class : Class
should be:

newName

...

I was also experiencing this problem - after changing the .xib filename manually. I have no idea why renaming by refactoring was grayed out but that was my first attempted solution to rename. I then made some IBOutlets, but dragging to the File's Owner didn't give me any options to connect to it.

I right clicked on File's Owner and noticed some warnings telling me there was no IBOutlet by the name of the variable it tried to reference.

Basically, since I changed the .xib filename manually, at least one of the above configurations did not automatically follow (makes sense since I did a manual operation).

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me try connecting the touch up inside connection of the button to files owner and then it will show up